# How to optimize this normalization function

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, optimization

I'm trying to write a normalization function for the individual r, g, and b arrays in an image. It also needs to take in max values for each of the rgb arrays so none of the generic normalization functions in libraries that I found fit the bill. After modifying some code from geeksforgeeks, I came up with this:

```
# Modified from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-normalize-an-array-in-numpy-in-python/
# Function to normalize array based on a consistent max value for rgb
def normal(arr, imgrMax, imggMax, imgbMax, alpha = 0, beta = 1):
    arr = arr.astype(np.float32)
    norm_arr = np.zeros_like(arr)
    norm_arr_r = []
    norm_arr_g = []
    norm_arr_b = []
    diff = beta - alpha
    diff_arr_r = imgrMax - np.min(arr[:,:, 0])
    for i in arr[:, :, 0]:
        # temp = (((i - min(arr))*diff)/diff_arr) + t_min
        temp = np.divide(np.multiply(i - np.min(arr[:, :, 0]), diff), diff_arr_r) + alpha
        norm_arr_r.append(temp)
    diff_arr_g = imggMax - np.min(arr[:,:, 1])
    for i in arr[:, :, 1]:
        temp = np.divide(np.multiply(i - np.min(arr[:, :, 1]), diff), diff_arr_g) + alpha
        norm_arr_g.append(temp) 
    diff_arr_b = imgbMax - np.min(arr[:,:, 2])
    for i in arr[:, :, 2]:
        temp = np.divide(np.multiply(i - np.min(arr[:, :, 2]), diff), diff_arr_b) + alpha
        norm_arr_b.append(temp) 
    norm_arr[:, :, 0] = norm_arr_r
    norm_arr[:, :, 1] = norm_arr_g
    norm_arr[:, :, 2] = norm_arr_b
    print(norm_arr)
    return norm_arr
```

It works but it takes 943 seconds to process 7 images, whereas when I use the cv2.normalize() function it takes 40 seconds for the same 7 images. I know this is a bit sloppy, but I'm not sure how else to make it work and I definitely don't know how to make it go fast. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html), the following is equivalent to your function.

```py
def normal(arr, imgrMax, imggMax, imgbMax, alpha=0, beta=1):
    arr = arr.astype(np.float32)
    imgMax = np.array([imgrMax, imggMax, imgbMax])

    # Equivalent to np.array([np.min(arr[:, :, 0]), np.min(arr[:, :, 1]), np.min(arr[:, :, 2])])
    arr_min = arr.reshape((-1, arr.shape[-1])).min(axis=0)

    diff = beta - alpha
    diff_arr = imgMax - arr_min
    norm_arr = ((arr - arr_min) * diff) / diff_arr + alpha
    return norm_arr
```

Let me know if this is still not enough.

Comment: This absolutely killed it! Thank you so much. I don't have 15 points yet so I can't upvote but this brought the processing time down to 6 seconds and it gives the exact same result as the one that took over 900 seconds. Incredible, gonna have to look into broadcasting some more.

Comment: @Crayfi you can't upvote, but you can accept this answer which I recommend doing

Comment: @dankal444 Thanks for the tip! I didn't know how to accept an answer before looking for it just now.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to beat optimized OpenCV code.

But seems you make unnecessary work in all the loops, seeking for `min` (without dependence to `i`) **every time**.

Just precalculate `minn = np.min(arr[:, :, 0])` before `for` loop and use this value inside